# Should I replace fallen gutters?

Tags: roof, gutters, water

This past winter a heavy snow fall ripped two sets of gutters off our house, and I haven't had a chance to re-hang them yet.  One is over our back door and it's really annoying having the running off hit you when you step out the back door, so they will be replaced as soon as I can.

The other set was over top of a flower bed at an inset corner (so there is a steady stream of water during a heavy rain formed where the two sections of the roof come together).  The only place the water seems to go is into the bed, about a foot from the base of the house. If I can avoid replacing them, I'd like to, but I don't want to risk a bigger issue down the road.

Do I need to replace this second set? Am I risking long-term damage to the foundation or some other issue I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *could* be risking damage to the foundation. It depends if the bed is properly graded or not. If the bed is graded properly, the water will run away from the house and the foundation. If not, the water could run towards the house.

After a heavy rainfall, see if the foundation concrete close to the dirt looks wet. If it stays wet looking for long after the rest of the foundation has dried, it could mean that water is running towards the foundation.

If that's the case, you have 3 options:

1. Fix the gutter.
2. Regrade the bed.
3. Run the risk of your foundation possibly being affected.

Answer (score 10):

Definitely replace the gutter.

Not only are you risking damage to the foundation, but if there's any wind when it rains your walls and windows will receive much more water than they should. This can cause all sorts of other problems like rot, seepage, and suchlike.

Answer (score 3):

Allowing rainwater to free fall from the roof can cause cosmetic issues, like dirt splatter all over your foundation and siding, but will also contribute to water in your basement.  The function of the gutter is to redirect this water away from the house so it doesn't gather up against the foundation below grade.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely replace the gutter, but before to do that make it sure the foundation is still okay and no damage around.Find out the source of tha main problem then fix it before to getting worse. problem.

Answer (score 1):

This IS a problem, one that you should repair.

If you have a basement, then the water will seep into the ground, then look for somewhere to go. You basement (if you have one) is a big, empty hole. Water can navigate into it, even if the basement walls are water-proofed. Water is surprisingly forceful, and very persistent. The water will end up causing long term damage if you let this continue.

The water can cause other damage, even if you don't have a basement. As that water runs off the roof and splashes down, it will splash against the house walls. This may cause moisture problems of its own in your walls.

So just fix the gutters. An immediate repair is always easier than fixing both the gutters and the problems the failed gutters will cause in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that the water is digging a hole you can put a large rock in the way to help direct the water away from the foundation.